# jQuery remove closest not working on elements added to DOM after page load

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have the following Rails loop that lists all `@team.authority_emails`:

```
<% if @team.nil? %>
  <% @team.authority_emails.collect.each_with_index do |a_e, index| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-11 columns">
        <input type="text" value="<%= a_e %>" name="authorities[]" class="authority-email">
      </div>
      <div class="large-1 columns">
        <a href="#" class="remove"><%= icon('fa fa-remove') %></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I use the following jQuery to add new input fields to the DOM:

```
$('#newAuthority').on("click", function() {

    var $newAuthorityCon = $(".new-authority-container");
    var $row = $('<div />', {
        class: 'row'
    }).appendTo($newAuthorityCon);
    var $large11 = $('<div />', {
        class: 'large-11 columns'
    }).appendTo($row);
    var $input = $('<input>', {
        type: 'text',
        placeholder: 'email@domain.com',
        class: 'authority-email'
    }).appendTo($large11);
    var $large1 = $('<div />', {
        class: 'large-1 columns'
    }).appendTo($row);
    var $remove = $('<a>', {
        href: '#',
        class: 'remove'
    }).html('<i class="fa fa-fa fa-remove"></i>').appendTo($large1);

    return false;
});
```

And I use the following jQuery to remove any existing or newly created inputs:

```
$('.remove').on("click", function() {

  $(this).closest('.row').remove();
  return false;

});
```

The above works correctly when removing inputs created by the Rails loop. However, when I try removing inputs created by the jQuery, the page jumps up and the input disappears. When I go to add another input I get two new inputs instead of one. I then click remove and both disappear. When I add another I get three inputs and so on and so forth. What's causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use event delegation [jquery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {

   $(this).closest('.row').remove();
   return false;

});
```